# How can I solve for the DC analysis of the CE transistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm new at learning transistors and amplifier. I've been studying this circuit and trying to compute the values for the DC analysis but I can't seem to get the same answers when I simulated it in LTSPICE.

This is the given circuit:

[image]

[image]

These are data from the simulation.

How can I solve for the Vb of Q1 if the resistor isn't connected to the Vcc?

Can I still use this to solve for it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You has placed C2 in reversed polarity !

Comment: thank you for that! i didn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

This type of calculation is not easy because there are too many unknowns in the circuit.
For example, we do not know the exact value of a \$V_{BE}\$ voltage, and also the \$\beta\$ value is also unknown.

But if we assumed the \$\beta = \infty\$ and some constant \$V_{BE}\$ value

We can write this KVL for this simplified schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9u1MA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$V_{CC} = I_{C1}R_C + V_{BE2} + I_DR_1+I_DR_2$$

$$I_DR_2=V_{BE1}+I_{C1} R_{E1} $$

And if we solve it we get this:

$$I_{C1} = \frac{ V_{CC} - \left(\frac{R_1 + 2R_2}{R_2}V_{BE}\right)}{ R_{E1} + R_{C1} +\frac{R_1}{R_2}R_{E1}} $$

And knowing that \$V_E = V_C - V_{BE2} = V_{CC} - I_{C1}R_{C1} - V_{BE2}\$

And \$V_B = V_E \times \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$

We have:

$$V_E = \frac{\left( \frac{R_{E1}}{R_{C1}} \times(V_{CC} - V_{BE})\right)+V_{BE}}{\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} + \frac{R_{E1}}{R_{C1}}}$$
$$ V_B = \frac{V_{CC} + V_{BE}\left(\frac{R_{C1}}{R_{E1}} -1\right)}{\left(1+\frac{R_1}{R_2}\right) +\frac{R_{C1}}{R_{E1}}}$$

Doing such a calculation does not have much sense. But here you have it.